# How to display the whole column value with GROUP_CONCAT in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL query that should display me 3 columns in result id, group_id and url. I'm using the `GROUP_CONCAT` function in order to get some concatenated urls. My problem is the `GROUP_CONCAT` case is truncated, I can't see the whole result. Here's the query result

```
ID | GROUP_ID | URLS
1      4        http://www.stackoverflow.....
```

So any help please to show the whole case value. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You *could* use this before running that `SELECT`:

```
SET SESSION group_concat_max_len = 1000000;
```

Or in `mysql.conf` to make it permanent (restart service to take effect):

```
[mysqld]
group_concat_max_len=1000000
```

But that's just covering up a bigger issue.
That limit has a reason. By default it is `1024`.
Perhaps look into changing the way you store that data.

For more details, check the [mysql docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_group_concat_max_len).

Comment: Thanks for that. It's helping me to understand